# OpenCL writing to an Image blocks

Tags: rust, opencl

I have this rust code using opencl3 crate. I am trying to learn OpenCL with Rust. The code is pretty simple, it attempts to create an image pass it to opencl and copies it. I am trying to learn about more complex operations, but I started with this simple program to get around it.

Rust code:

```
pub struct ImageCopier {
    context: Context,
    queue: CommandQueue,
}

impl ImageCopier {
    pub fn new(context: Context, queue: CommandQueue) -> Self {
        ImageCopier {
            context,
            queue,
        }
    }

    pub fn copy(&self) {
        let mut image_buffer = self.generate_image();
        let (width, height) = image_buffer.dimensions();
        let pixels: Vec<u8> = image_buffer.into_raw();
        let format = cl_image_format {
            image_channel_order: CL_RGBA,
            image_channel_data_type: CL_UNSIGNED_INT8,
        };
        let desc = cl_image_desc {
            image_type: CL_MEM_OBJECT_IMAGE2D,
            image_width: width as _,
            image_height: height as _,
            image_depth: 1,
            image_array_size: 1,
            image_row_pitch: 0,
            image_slice_pitch: 0,
            num_mip_levels: 0,
            num_samples: 0,
            buffer: ptr::null_mut(),
        };
        let mut opencl_image_input = unsafe {
            Image::create(
                &self.context,
                CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR,
                &format,
                &desc,
                pixels.as_ptr() as *mut c_void,
            )
            .unwrap()
        };
        let program = Program::create_and_build_from_source(&self.context, PROGRAM_SOURCE, "")
            .expect("Program::create_and_build_from_source failed");
        let kernel = Kernel::create(&program, KERNEL_NAME).expect("Kernel::create failed");
        let worksize: usize = (width * height).try_into().unwrap();
        let output_image = self.create_output_image(width, height);
        let kernel_event = unsafe {
            ExecuteKernel::new(&kernel)
                .set_arg(&opencl_image_input)
                .set_arg(&output_image)
                .set_global_work_size(worksize)
                .enqueue_nd_range(&self.queue)
                .unwrap()
        };

        let mut events: Vec<cl_event> = Vec::default();
        events.push(kernel_event.get());
    }

    fn generate_image(&self) -> image::ImageBuffer<image::Rgba<u8>, Vec<u8>> {
        let img = image::ImageBuffer::from_fn(512, 512, |x, y| {
            let near_midline = (x + y < 536) && (x + y > 488);
    
            if near_midline {
                image::Rgba([196, 50, 50, 255u8])
            } else {
                image::Rgba([50, 50, 50, 255u8])
            }
        });
    
        img
    }

    fn create_output_image(&self, width: u32, height:u32) -> opencl3::memory::Image {
        let format = cl_image_format {
            image_channel_order: CL_RGBA,
            image_channel_data_type: CL_UNSIGNED_INT8,
        };

        let desc = cl_image_desc {
            image_type: CL_MEM_OBJECT_IMAGE2D,
            image_width: width as _,
            image_height: height as _,
            image_depth: 1,
            image_array_size: 1,
            image_row_pitch: 0,
            image_slice_pitch: 0,
            num_mip_levels: 0,
            num_samples: 0,
            buffer: ptr::null_mut(),
        };

        let output_opencl_image = unsafe { Image::create(
            &self.context,
            CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY,
            &format,
            &desc,
            ptr::null_mut(),
            ).unwrap()
        };

        output_opencl_image
    }
```

}

Kernel code

```
__constant sampler_t sampler = CLK_NORMALIZED_COORDS_FALSE | CLK_ADDRESS_CLAMP | CLK_FILTER_LINEAR;

__kernel void read_write_image(read_only image2d_t input_image, write_only image2d_t output_image)
{
    int i = get_global_id(0);
    int j = get_global_id(1);
    float tmp = read_imagef(input_image, sampler, (int2) (i,j)).x;
    write_imagef(output_image, (int2) (i,j), (float4) (tmp,0,0,1));
}
```

When I run this code in my main it never finishes running, like it is blocked or something. What am I doing wrong? Also, how can I read back the output image into a buffer so I save it locally?

Comment: For those interested, I opened an issue https://github.com/kenba/opencl3/issues/65